# How to subscribe to long-running source of messages

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm trying reactiveui, and I don't understand how to make a simple scenario work: I have a method that listens for messages in a chat room. So, it's long running, and fires events when a message is found.

using reactiveui, I want to kick off this long running method when the window opens, and have new messages populated on the screen in a listbox. Because I'm using rx, I assumed I'd need an IObseravble version of the long running method, so I made one like this:

```
    public static IObservable<Message> ObservableStream(int roomid, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Observable.Create<Message>(
            async (IObserver<Message> observer) =>
                {
                 ...
                }
         );
    }
```

But, I've no idea how to plumb this into reactiveui. Would I need a `ObservableAsPropertyHelper<List<Message>>` ? At the moment I just kick off the long running method in a `Task.Factory.Startnew` and then on events I manually add to a list of messages, which is bound to the front end list box. This works but it's not using any reactiveui, and it strikes me that there should be a reactiveui way to do this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private ThreadSafeObservableCollection<Message> _Messages;
    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection<Message> Messages
    {
        get { return _Messages; }
        set { 
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x._Messages, value);
        }
    }


    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Client.NewMessage += (sender, args) => Messages.Add(args.Message);
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Client.GetStream(token), token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);

    }
}


// IN the code-behind

this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.Messages, x => x.MessageList.ItemsSource);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var Messages = ObservableStream(...).CreateCollection();
```

Then, you can listen to Messages for `ItemAdded` et al, or just bind it via `OneWayBind` and the UI will automatically update.

> Would I need a ObservableAsPropertyHelper> ?

So, normally this would be a good idea for most Web API calls, but since you're *streaming* the list instead of *replacing* the list every time, you need to create a collection at startup and add items to it as they come in. Another way you could do this is:

```
var Messages = new ReactiveList<Message>();
ObservableStream(...).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(x => Message.Add(x));
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. Can you tell me what the advantage of `ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)` is, I'm not sure how I should be using the Scheduler in your lib...

Comment: Because the source of your messages are from background threads (because of the async x => ...), you need to make sure the `Message.Add` gets called on the UI thread (I fixed some code above, CreateCollection does this for you)